# Angular2 - Nested component with Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-reactive-forms

I've written a component to manage my model (model.component.ts) and I want to use it inside 2 others components (create and show).
In model.component, I'm using Reactive forms to control the values. Because my model needs to manage a list dynamically, I rebuild this Reactive form part when the list is changing.

My problem is when I load a model from show.component, model.component doesn't like it and tells me :

```
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'categories -> deco'
```

Maybe I've written from the wrong way, so if you have a solution for me it will be very helpful :)

**model.component.ts**

```
export class InvoicesModelComponent implements OnInit {

    createForm: FormGroup;
    @Input() invoice: Invoice = new Invoice();
    @Output() invoiceChange = new EventEmitter<Invoice>();

    @Output() created = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private _invoiceService: InvoiceService
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createForm = this.makeFormGroup();
    }

    makeFormGroup(): FormGroup{
        let contact_group = this._formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', [Validators.required]],
            company: ['', [Validators.required]],
            job: ['', [Validators.required]],
            hotel: ['', [Validators.required]],
            email: ['', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.email]],
            phone: ['', [Validators.required]],
        });

        let categories = this._formBuilder.group({});

        return this._formBuilder.group({
            contact: contact_group,
            categories: categories,
        });
    }

    makeFormGroupCategories() {
        let categoriesGroup: any = {};
        this.invoice.categories.forEach((category, categoryKey) => {
            categoriesGroup[category.type] = this.makeFormGroupProducts(category.products);
        });

        this.createForm.setControl('categories', this._formBuilder.group(categoriesGroup));
    }

    makeFormGroupProducts(products) {
        let productsArray: any[] = [];
        products.forEach((product) => {
            productsArray.push(
                this._formBuilder.group({
                    name: [product.name, [Validators.required]],
                    quantity: [product.quantity, [Validators.required]],
                    days: [product.days, [Validators.required]],
                    coefficient: [product.coefficient, [Validators.required]],
                    amountHT: [product.amountHT, [Validators.required]],
                })
            );
        });
        return this._formBuilder.array(productsArray);
    }
}
```

**model.component.html**

```
<md-card-content>
    <div formGroupName="categories">
        <md-tab-group (selectChange)="setCategoryActiveTab($event)" dynamicHeight="true">
            <md-tab *ngFor="let category of invoice.categories" formGroupName="{{category.type}}" label="{{category.name}}">
                <div>
                    <div *ngFor="let product of category.products; let i=index" formGroupName="{{i}}">
                        <div>
                            <md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
                                <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Name" name="row_name" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="product.name" />
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
                                <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Quantity" name="product_quantity" formControlName="quantity" [(ngModel)]="product.quantity" />
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
                                <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Days" name="product_days" formControlName="days" [(ngModel)]="product.days" />
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
                                <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="AmountHT" name="product_amountHT" formControlName="amountHT" [(ngModel)]="product.amountHT" />
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
                                <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Coefficient" name="product_coefficient" formControlName="coefficient" [(ngModel)]="product.coefficient" />
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
                            <input mdInput disabled type="text" name="product_totalHT" value="{{ product.totalHT | number:'2.2-2' | replace:',':' ' }} €" />
                        </md-input-container>
                        <button md-icon-button (click)="removeProduct($event, product, category)"  mdTooltip='Remove {{product.description}}'>
                            <md-icon> clear </md-icon>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tab-group>
    </div>
</md-card-content>
```

**show.component.ts**

```
export class InvoicesShowComponent implements OnInit {

    invoice: Invoice = new Invoice();

    @ViewChild(InvoicesModelComponent) invoicesModelComponent: InvoicesModelComponent;

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _invoiceService: InvoiceService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = this._route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this._invoiceService.findById(id)
            .then((invoice: Invoice) => {
                this.invoice = invoice;
                this.invoicesModelComponent.makeFormGroupCategories();
            })
        ;
    }

}
```

**show.component.html**

```
<client-invoices-model [(invoice)]="invoice"></client-invoices-model>
```

EDIT :
[Here is my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wTwVSFAHI9R4QvuJg7YV?). You can update `loadFromNested` boolean in `app.component.ts` to see working when my model is loaded directly in `nested.component` but fails from `app.component`.

Comment: what will this line do `let categories = this._formBuilder.group({});`

Comment: Post your template file...

Comment: I've added model.component.html

Comment: Probably the error is on this line `...formGroupName="{{category.type}}"...` Your `form group` is only that you posted? Or do you have some group inside `categories`?

Comment: The form group has other fields, but not inside `categories`. The weird thing is if I call `this._invoiceService.findById` in `model.component.ts`, it works.

Comment: Almost impossible to help here without a Plnkr. I wouldn't mix FormBuilder and "native" FormGroup creation this way. BTW I've never seen something like `formGroupName="{{i}}"`, always `[formControlName]="i"`. But that's not the problem here, it should work either way.

Comment: [Here is my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wTwVSFAHI9R4QvuJg7YV?). You can update `loadFromNested` boolean in `app.component.ts` to see working when my model is loaded directly in `nested.component` but fails from `app.component`.

Comment: What do you expect? You don't wait until child component gets new input value. It will happen only next tick. Here i am directly setting value to child https://plnkr.co/edit/lQCOhB3tfzyXN0qv9W81?p=preview

Comment: That's a good idea. I d'ont understand why the 2ways binding is not "working" here. If I set `ìnvoice` in `app.component` and use the 2ways binding in my template, `invoice` in `nested.component` won't be directly updated?

Comment: Why on earth are you using Classes instead of Interfaces? :P Make your life easier and use interfaces... I see no need for classes...

Comment: Because I need some functions on my object, like `getTotalVAT()`. It's easier for me to do `object.getTotalVAT()`.